# ActiveMQ: NullPointerException on broker while checking for authorization

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, osgi, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.3.0 under OSGi environment from two years without any notable issue.

Now, I need to add authorization management for users publishing/subscribing to particular topics.
For this purpose, I developed a plugin which implements org.apache.activemq.security.MessageAuthorizationPolicy: in the method

```
public boolean isAllowedToConsume(ConnectionContext context, Message message)
```

where I read the incoming message, I check that the current user is allowed to consume such a message and I return true/false accordingly to this check.
In particular, I use text messages (short XML fragments...), so, I use this snippet to read the current TextMessage:

```
if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
   String xmlText = "";
   try {
       xmlText = xml.getText();
       System.out.println(xmlText);
       ... //parse the message and check for permission...
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        ... //manage exception
    }
}
```

It seems to me (but maybe I'm wrong!!) that this code creates a race with the code contained in org.apache.activemq.openwire.v5.MessageMarshaller:

```
public void tightMarshal2(OpenWireFormat wireFormat, Object o, DataOutput dataOut, BooleanStream bs) throws IOException {
   ...
   tightMarshalByteSequence2(info.getContent(), dataOut, bs); //here, info.getContent() is null!!
   ...
}
```

and in fact I receive a NullPointerException whose stacktrace is:

```
 Exception in thread "BrokerService" 
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v5.BaseDataStreamMarshaller.tightMarshalByteSequence2(BaseDataStreamMarshaller.java:431)
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v5.MessageMarshaller.tightMarshal2(MessageMarshaller.java:180)
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v5.ActiveMQMessageMarshaller.tightMarshal2(ActiveMQMessageMarshaller.java:89)
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v5.ActiveMQTextMessageMarshaller.tightMarshal2(ActiveMQTextMessageMarshaller.java:89)
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.tightMarshalNestedObject2(OpenWireFormat.java:430)
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v5.BaseDataStreamMarshaller.tightMarshalNestedObject2(BaseDataStreamMarshaller.java:136)
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v5.MessageDispatchMarshaller.tightMarshal2(MessageDispatchMarshaller.java:105)
at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.marshal(OpenWireFormat.java:240)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.oneway(TcpTransport.java:166)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.oneway(InactivityMonitor.java:237)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.oneway(TransportFilter.java:83)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:104)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:40)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.dispatch(TransportConnection.java:1190)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processDispatch(TransportConnection.java:779)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.iterate(TransportConnection.java:815)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:122)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:43)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Now, if I remove the snippet to read the XML content of the message in isAllowedToConsume(...), all seeems returning fine, but I need such a control!!!

So, is there a way to correctly read a TextMessage without affecting other consumers?

Thank you very much and sorry for the long question!!

Bye
cghersi

## Revision 1 (@nico_ekito):

Here there is the complete isAllowedToConsume() method:

```
public boolean isAllowedToConsume(ConnectionContext context, Message message) { 
  String msgFrom = message.getDestination().getPhysicalName();              
  String textOfMsg = "";
  if(message instanceof TextMessage){
    TextMessage xml = (TextMessage)message;
    try {
      textOfMsg = xml.getText();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
      return false;
    }
  } else    
    return false;   

  //do my checks on textOfMsg returning true/false...       
}
```

Comment: Please show the complete isAllowedToConsume() methood. Because you may have made a confusion : the Message parameter of the isAllowedToConsume() method is a [org.apache.activemq.command.Message](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.4.0/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/Message.html) and not a javax.jms.Message

Comment: Please edit your question to include the missing source code.

Comment: @nico_ekito I added the Revision #1

Comment: Does the NullPointerException appear if you return `true` in the `isAllowedToConsume` method ?

Comment: @nico_ekito Sorry, I cannot understand: do you mean if I replace my code with "return true", or only when my code returns true?
In the first case: no, if I don't cope with the message isAllowedToConsume method, all seems running ok. In the latter case, I'm not able to virify such a situation

Comment: What I don't understand is that you do not make any modification in the `message` variable (at least in the provided source code) ? And also, I don't think that you ever enter the "if" portion of your code, since the `Message` type is a org.apache.activemq.command.Message (which cannot be a `TextMessage`). So sorry, I don't see anythoing :( Maybe you're hitting a bug from ActiveMQ.

Comment: I double checked this, and I confirm that I enter into the if portion. I can also correctly read the content of the message. Regarding the fact that I don't modify the message, this is exactly the point that is puzzling me!! Perhaps reading the message with the getText() method dirties the message that is concurrently read from other ActiveMQ threads?

Comment: I think you may be right : reading the message via getText() actually consumes the InputStream (see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.activemq/com.springsource.org.apache.activemq/5.2.0/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQTextMessage.java#ActiveMQTextMessage.getText%28%29).